# Android studio emulator always keep windows to crash

Tags: windows, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to run apps on android emulator and after 15 minutes of working , there is some lags then screen was stopped then I got this error .

Android studio version : 4.1.3  ,
Window version : 21H1 (OS build 19043.1165)  ,
Installed plugins : flutter , android wifi adb , dart , bloc , jetbrains marketplace , gauge , kotlin , markdown  ,

PC specifications :

Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz   2.80 GHz
Ram : 16.0 GB
display adapters : Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 , NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design

[image]

Comment: ok... any more details? which version of Android Studio are you using, which version of Windows are using? which plugins are installed? what's the PC specs? We can't guess with just a picture.

Comment: sorry I edited it

Comment: were you using the wifi adb have you tried removing that plugin and connecting your phone directly? It may be a drivers issue.

Comment: I don't use wifi adb now , I face this problem before I had installed it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the RAM modules ...and also watch the thermal sensors.

`DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILED` generally means, that some device broke away from the system - where corrupt RAM and overheating are the most common causes, besides other defective devices. If you would like to know the *concrete* cause ... just run `eventvwr.msc` and find the crash event.

There's even a troubleshooter: https://www.windows.con/stopcode
(which probably won't help much, when it's one of the said causes).

As a matter of fact, a notebook is not the optimum to house a GPU.

Comment: In Emulated performance in emulator settings , if graphics option is software GLES 2.0 not hardware it works good but it's a little slow , so do you think that  the reason for this is the gpu ?